# Beginner Probability - What's wrong with my use of conditioning here?

Tags: probability

Problem stated below (from Ross's book).

**Can you point out where I'm going off the rails?**

1. Let $E =$ the event that the first person to arrive has to wait longer than 10 minutes.
2. Therefore the final answer will be the $P(E)$
3. Let $M =$ the event that the man arrives first
4. Let $F =$ girl arrives first
5. Then $P(E) = P(E|M)P(M) + P(E|F)P(F)$
6. I'm pretty sure that the $P(M) = P(F) = \frac{1}{2}$ since the arrival times of the girl and guy are both uniformly distributed between the same interval
7. I'm pretty sure because of symmetry the $P(E|M) = P(E|F) = $ the probability that the man waits 10 minutes for the girl
8. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the arrival times for the man and woman
9. The probability that the man waits 10 minutes for the girl $= P(Y-X>10)$
10. Therefore $P(E) = \frac{1}{2}P(Y-X>10) + \frac{1}{2}P(Y-X>10) = P(Y-X>10)$ and not $2P(Y-X>10)$

---

**Edit, correct answer is:**
$P(E) = P(Y-X>10|Y>X)P(Y>X) + P(X-Y>10|X>Y)P(X>Y)$
$=2 \cdot P(Y-X>10)$

And the last equality happens because note that the first term reduces to

$$P(Y-X>10|Y>X)P(Y>X) = \frac{P(Y-X>10 , Y>X)P(Y>X)}{P(Y>X)}$$

$$=P(Y-X>10,Y>X) = P(Y-X>10)$$

And note that the second term has equal probability as the first. Therefore you get $2 \cdot P(Y-X>10)$

---

Flaw was in step 9 I incorrectly thought $P(E|M) = P(Y-X>10)$

I was thinking that that already implied some kind of conditioning which is why I originally excluded it.

---

[image: Sheldon Ross waiting problem]

Comment: In 9 you forgot you have given $X>Y$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Does the conditioning that the girl arrives first not cover X>Y?

Comment: It does, but in 9 you express the unconditioned probability.

Comment: Hmmm... can yout point out how I would fix the following? It looks like I need to factor in P(X>Y) somewhere: P(E) =.5 * P(Y−X>10) + .5 * P(Y−X>10)

Comment: You don't need to factor... you already did it using total probability. Now you need $P(Y-X>10|Y>X)$ and vice versa. So, when you calculate the value, just use integration limits that agree with this expression.

Comment: Crap I will have to think on this for a while. Can you confirm that this is correct? P(E|M) * P(M) = P(Y-X>10 | Y > X) P(M) = .5 * P(Y-X>10 | Y > X) = P(Y-X>10)

Comment: As $P(M)=P(Y>X)$ it's straightforward that $P(Y-X>10|Y>X)P(M)=P(Y-X>10)$.

Comment: Thanks... that makes 100% sense to me in terms of things cancelling out. However my intuition would've been to turn P(Y>X) into .5 which I believe is correct and then I wouldn't have seen that stuff cancelling out. My intution also would not've been to add that extra condition Y>X in the first place. Anyway it's on me to meditate on this for a while. I appreciate the help. I'd give you the green check mark but this is in the comments...